# Max number of warnings

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, compiler-warnings

Is there a way to stop compilation after max number of warnings without convert them to error and using -fmax-errors?

I have third party library which has warning and I don't like to change them.

Answer (score 0):

Among the 550 options returned by

```
g++ --help=common
```

you can grep for "max":

```
g++ --help=common | grep max
```

a find "-fmax-errors"

> -fmax-errors=       Maximum number of errors to report.
>
> -fpack-struct=      Set initial maximum structure member alignment.

However there is no "-fmax-warnings".

You can also check among the 464 warning options:

```
g++ --help=warnings | grep max
```

which only returns:

> -Woverlength-strings        Warn if a string is longer than the
> maximum portable

**Conclusion:**

I think something like the "-fmax-warnings" option you are looking for does not exist.